# script says not found although executable exists

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following small script to test whether I can use a local version of the JVM:

```
#!/bin/sh
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

It fails with:

```
./test.sh: 2: ./test.sh: ~/bin/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java: not found
```

However, when I enter the command directly on the command line it works:

```
user@computer $ ~/bin/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is JAVA_HOME set ?

Comment: yes it is set to the value printed in the error message: ~/bin/jdk1.8.0_72

Comment: set the JAVA_HOME with absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is not expanding the symbol ~ (home directory) , and so you end up in the error. Try exporting the full path of the binary.

Comment: ...because `~` is only expanded if it is the first character -- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion